# keep JavaScript array variable during post-back

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How can I keep the values of ;ctrlIDhdnImageSourceArrayJs,ctrlIDhdnElementsArayJsHidden  during a web page life-cycle...

```
"<script language = javascript>
                                            debugger;
                                            var ctrlIDhdnImageSourceArrayJs     = '" + this.hdnImageSourceArrayJs.ClientID + @"';
                                            var ctrlIDhdnElementsArayJsHidden   = '" + this.hdnElementsArayJsHidden.ClientID + @"';
                                            var loaderF = function getImagesData()
                                            {

                                                var fieldNamesList=[" + fieldNames + @"];
                                                return KrediKartUtils.LoadImagesData('0','" + KrediKartiRow.Row.SmartPenFormNo + @"',fieldNamesList,LoadImagesDataCallBack);        
                                            };


                                            function LoadImagesDataCallBack()
                                            {
                                                    if(images.length > 0) 
                                                    {
                                                        var numImages = 10; /*10 ar 10 ar göster*/
                                                        while(images.length > 0 && numImages-- > 0)
                                                        {
                                                            document.getElementById(elements.shift()).src =images.shift();

                                                        }
                                                       /* setTimeout(fetchImages, 1000); *//*1sn de bir*/
                                                    LoadImagesDataCallBack();
                                                    }

                                            }
                                            if('False' == '" + Page.IsPostBack.ToString() + @"')
                                            {

                                              var images=[" + imageSourceArrayJs + @"];
                                              var elements=[" + elementsArayJs + @"];  
                                              document.getElementById(ctrlIDhdnImageSourceArrayJs).value="""+imageSourceArrayJs+@""";
                                              document.getElementById(ctrlIDhdnElementsArayJsHidden).value="""+elementsArayJs+@""";  
                                              window.onload = loaderF;                                  
                                            }else{
                                                var images=[document.getElementById(ctrlIDhdnImageSourceArrayJs).value];
                                                var elements=[document.getElementById(ctrlIDhdnElementsArayJsHidden).value];                         
                                               LoadImagesDataCallBack();
                                            }

                                            </script>";
```

Comment: I think you can make some effort formatting your source code.

Comment: @ this is a string and I register to Page;
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(ui_SUBMVGInfo), "SmartPenPutImages", strSmartPenJs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep any value or values during a new request, you will need to include those values with the request.

This means that for a GET, you need to include the values in the querystring

```
?myValue=1&myArray=1,2,3,4,5
```

And for a POST you need to append your values to the posted data (usually by placing them inside form fields during the "onsubmit" event.

You can then either process these server side and write out their value to the page or retrieve them from the document.location using JavaScript.

Comment: @ I want the images array alive during post-back. I mean I get the object but not array